# derivative of following function defined in proper domain w.r.t x

Tags: calculus

I want to find derivative of following function defined in proper domain w.r.t x

$$
e^{3x} \log{2x}
$$

Comment: Do you mean $e^{3x}\log (2x$)?  If so, you need braces around the $3x$ to make the $x$ come out in the exponent.  Or is it $\log_2 (x)$?

Comment: In any case of the problem, do you know the multiplication and chain rules for derivatives?

Comment: Please write this in question form, not in request form.

Answer (score 1):

Use the product rule which says that if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions then $(f(x)g(x))' = f(x) \cdot g'(x) + g(x) \cdot f'(x)$ and note that the derivative of $e^{ax}= ae^{ax}$ for some $a \neq 0$ and derivative of $\log{x}$ is $\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: @Ross: Typo, forgive me

Comment: @Ross: I have rectified it. Thanks for pointing out the error.